# How can I close a div tag and open a new one after a number of content elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div container (containing child elements), that needs to be splitted in several ones (depending on content length)

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Element 1</p>
    <p>Element 2</p>
    <p>Element 3</p>
    <p class="here">Element 4</p>
    <p>Element 5</p>
    <p>Element 6</p>
</div>
```

I've already tried `insertBefore()`:

```
$('</div></div class="box">').insertBefore($('.here'));
```

But this makes something like that (what I don't understand):

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Element 1</p>
    <p>Element 2</p>
    <p>Element 3</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="here">Element 4</p>
    <p>Element 5</p>
    <p>Element 6</p>
</div>
```

I'm in need to split my 'box' container in several ones. Is there any other way to manage this, to get it like that?

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Element 1</p>
    <p>Element 2</p>
    <p>Element 3</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p class="here">Element 4</p>
    <p>Element 5</p>
    <p>Element 6</p>
</div>
```

Background: The content height of each `<p>` is added. When a specific total height is reached, I need to close the current and open a new 'box' div.

I've also read similar threads without finding (or maybe understanding) any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appendTo` to append the new `.box` to the body, then use `.append` to move all elements that are `.here` or come after `.here` to that new `.box`:

```js
$('<div class="box"></div>')
  .appendTo('body')
  .append($('.here, .here ~ *'));
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p>Element 1</p>
  <p>Element 2</p>
  <p>Element 3</p>
  <p class="here">Element 4</p>
  <p>Element 5</p>
  <p>Element 6</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap property! For example :

```
$(".here").wrap( "<div class="box"></div>");
```